# Spearman rank correlation between factors in R

Tags: r, correlation

I have data like the following:

```
directions <- c("North", "East", "South", "South")
x<-factor(directions, levels= c("North", "East", "South", "West"))

cities <- c("New York","Rome","Paris","London")
y<-factor(cities, levels= c("New York","Rome","Paris","London"))
```

How can I calculate the Spearman rank correlation between `x` and `y`?

**EDIT**

As suggested by @user20650 and @dcarlson comments, the variables must have a ranking such that one value is greater or less than another value. This is the case, because `North`, `East` etc. are keywords that are sorted according to their presence in a document.

Comment: ... although it is more common to use chi squared tests, mutual information etc depending on the hypothesis for categorical data

Comment: Spearman is a rank correlation coefficient that assumes the variables have a ranking such that one value is greater or less than another value. Your data do not have that property since North is not greater than West or less than East. New York is not greater than Rome or less than London. As @user20650 suggested, you need to use chi square.

Comment: I edited the post. Thank you. I missed an important information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get Spearman's correlation with factors you will have to convert them to their underlying numeric code:

```
cor(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y), method="spearman")
# [1] 0.9486833
cor.test(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y), method="spearman")
# 
#   Spearman's rank correlation rho
# 
# data:  as.numeric(x) and as.numeric(y)
# S = 0.51317, p-value = 0.05132
# alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
# sample estimates:
#       rho 
# 0.9486833 
# 
# Warning message:
# In cor.test.default(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y), method = "spearman") :
#   Cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

Note the warning about ties which make it difficult to compute an exact p-value. You can use `spearman_test` in package `coin` for data with ties:

```
library(coin)
spearman_test(as.numeric(x)~as.numeric(y))
# 
#   Asymptotic Spearman Correlation Test
# 
# data:  as.numeric(x) by as.numeric(y)
# Z = 1.6432, p-value = 0.1003
# alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
```